# ElasticSearch Nest .Raw QueryDescriptor renders empty json, instead of my custom query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use .Raw method of QueryDescriptor for adding a custom query section into my query:

```
var dmaxPrice = maxPrice.HasValue ? (double?)maxPrice.Value : 100000d;
var dminPrice = minPrice.HasValue ? (double?)minPrice.Value : 0d;

mustTerms.Add(mt => mt.Raw(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "{{ \"range\": {{ \"price\": {{ \"gte\": {0}, \"lte\": {1} }} }} }}", dminPrice, dmaxPrice)));
```

This code produces query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "linear": {
            "createDate": {
              "origin": "2015-03-16T14:02:37.4393456Z",
              "scale": "1d",
              "decay": 0.5
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see here, Nest puts an empty json instead of my query. Why is this? How can I get Nest to use my query instead of this empty json?

Note: I am using .Raw because when I use .Range, Nest does not render boundaries of the query correctly. I asked another question for that: [Nest renders range boundaries as string instead of double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077400/nest-renders-range-boundaries-as-string-instead-of-double)

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work, but QueryRaw does his job `this.Client.Search<dynamic>(s => s.QueryRaw("yourQuery"))`. Hope I'll be back later with a proper answer.